# Can a pointer be set to null if new operator fails?

Tags: c++, pointers, new-operator

If a pointer is allocated with memory by the new operator and the allocation isn't successful, is it safe to set the pointer to nullptr in the catch block?

```
foo* var;
try {
    var = new foo[size];
}
catch (std::bad_alloc& e) {
    std::cout << "Error: " << e.what() << "\n";
    var = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: The pointer is never assigned if `operator new` throws. So, yes, it is safe to set it to `nullptr`. In fact, you should never leave it uninitialized.

Comment: conversely if you do `foo* var = nullptr;` before doing anything you don't have to set to `nullptr` explicitly

Comment: Why not use `new (std::nothrow)`, such as `foo *var = new(std::nothrow) foo[size]`?   It returns a null pointer if it fails, and doesn't throw.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

An Alternate approach :

By default, when the new operator is used to allocate memory and the handling function is unable to do so, a bad_alloc exception is thrown.
But when nothrow is used as argument for new, it returns a null pointer instead.

Therefore in your case you can also use the below syntax.

```
foo* var = new (std::nothrow) foo[size];

if (var == nullptr)
{
   //allocation failed
}
```